# How to find the release of the deployed pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have deployed the pod in the **Kubernetes** using the **helm** install command. 
Now I need to delete the **pod** but I have not noted down the release name of the pod.

Is there any way to find out the release name of the deployed pod?

Comment: If your deployment spec applies the [standard labels](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_best_practices/labels/) to the pods it generates, you can get the value of the pods’ `app.kubernetes.io/instance` labels.  `helm list` should also list out everything Helm is managing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running "helm list" to see all the release names? If you don't have too many releases or pods you might be able to find your release name by comparing with the chart name.

Answer (score 0):

For the "helm list" command to work correctly you should add the namespace:

```
helm list -n <namespace>
```